# how to drop table if exists in pre-copy script azure synapse pipeline Copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have an azure synapse pipeline which runs fine if target tables already exist ... Copy activity pre-copy script is

> @{concat('drop  table ', item().target_schema, '.', item().target_object)}

however I need to edit above syntax to first check if table exists then only drop table if it exists ... below is legal sql server syntax

> IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[myschema].[mytable]') AND type in (N'U'))
> DROP TABLE [myschema].[mytable]
> GO

As you can see my pre-copy script is parameterized since my azure synapse analytics pipeline is doing these Activities :

```
Lookup -> ForEach -> Copy
```

so the pre-copy script syntax must also be parameterized

How do I implement the IF EXISTS logic yet put that into the parameterized pre-copy script syntax ?

The following guesses for the pre-copy script ... all error out

> if object_id (item().target_schema, '.', item().target_object,'U') is not null drop table item().target_schema, '.', item().target_object

below fails

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @{item().target_schema}.@{item().target_object}

with error

> "message": "ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Parse error at line: 1, column: 12: Incorrect syntax near 'IF'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Parse error at line: 1, column: 12: Incorrect syntax near 'IF'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=103010,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=103010,State=1,Message=Parse error at line: 1, column: 12: Incorrect syntax near 'IF'.,},],'",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my lookup output array which I have given to ForEach.

```
[
        {
            "table_name": "one",
            "schema_name": "dbo"
        },
        {
            "table_name": "two",
            "schema_name": "dbo"
        }
]
```

I reproduced the above scenario with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @{item().schema_name}.@{item().table_name}` command in pre-copy script of copy activity and got same error.

[image]

I tried the same command in synapse SQL database and ended up with same error.

[image]

As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#d-dropping-a-table-using-if-exists), the reason for this error might be the above command only applies to **SQL Server** and **not SQL DW**.

> The following guesses for the pre-copy script ... all error out
>
> if object_id (item().target_schema, '.', item().target_object,'U') is not null drop table item().target_schema, '.', item().target_object

I am able to drop the table in pre-copy script by using string interpolation with above command like below.

```
if object_id ('@{item().schema_name}.@{item().table_name}','U') is not null drop table @{item().schema_name}.@{item().table_name};
```

[image]

[image]